# In LilyPond (piano staff) how can I type two eighth notes for different hands?

Tags: lilypond

In LilyPond, while writing a piano staff, how can I type two eighth notes, so that one is played with the left and the other with the right hand?

> Example. I want to produce this highlighted separation:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order not to complicate the example by adding additional spacing until LilyPond prefers to pick a kneed beam on its own, I am using a voicing change to get this, moving from "first voice" settings in the lower staff to "fourth voice" setting in the higher.  Usually `\voiceOne`/`\voiceTwo` (can be implied by `<< ... \\ ... >>`) should be used for the outermost voices in a staff, but since the voice from the staff below is likely only an occasional visitor, I am giving it the `\voiceFour` treatment.  If the resulting arrangement is not satisfactory, one might temporarily adjust the lower voice of the upper staff to `\voiceFour` instead and return it afterwards (except that in this minimal example there is no separate history afterwards) to `\voiceTwo`.

```
global = { \key e \minor \time 2/4 }
{
  <<
    \new Staff = "high"
    { \global
      \new Voice {
        << { e''8 b' } \\ <e' b'>4 >>
        r4
      }
    }
    \new Staff = "low" \with { \clef bass }
    { \global
      \new Voice { \voiceOne g8
           \change Staff = "high" \voiceFour
           b
           \change Staff = "low" \oneVoice
           r4
         }
    }
  >>
}
```

[image: Kneed beam example.]

Answer (score 3):

You use multiple voices.  Here is a small example which semi-manually puts beams in the second of two voices in a `<< {first voice} \\ {second voice} >>` construct as the autobeamer does not work across skips or rests.

```
\relative
{
  \key e\major
  \time 3/4
  <<
    \repeat unfold 24 { s16 e'' } \\
    <<
      \repeat unfold 2
      { gis s e s dis s e s fis s e s e s gis s fis s gis s a s fis s }
      \repeat unfold 12 { s[ s s s] }
    >>
  >>
}
```

[image: Compiled result]

Comment: Thanks for your help (+1). I actually was thinking of writing it in two separated staffs (piano, with bass + treble keys). I edited the question adding the required form.